# Dynamically creating instances of a class using list of strings as variable names for instances

Tags: python, class

Lets say I want to produce multiple instances of a class (e.g. a `Car` class).

I have the variable names I need to use in a list:

```
cars = ['Mustang', 'Camaro', 'Challenger']
```

How can I loop through the `cars` list and create an instance of the `Car` class with the variable name being the string within the `cars` list.

Essentially doing the same as:

```
Mustang = Car()
Camaro = Car()
Challenger = Car()
```

I realise that dynamically creating variables is frowned upon, however I am using this to create instances of a class for each participant in a study, therefore I have their ID numbers in a list and want to use this ID number as the variable name for the class instance.

Comment: This isn't just "frowned upon", it's an anti-pattern. It also makes no sense. You pretty much are saying "I know this is a bad design, and I want to do it anway" because...?

Comment: `globals()["Mustang"] = Car()` (with all the exclamation marks).

Comment: The name of the variable is of no importance, why not just use a dict? it's the same thing anyway, to some extent. Just `cars = {}` then `cars['Mustang'] = Car()` and so on. Then you haven't got to do anything weird `globals`. Once those variables with those names exist, how are you going to reference them anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it helps: https://repl.it/OAQv

```
class Car:
    pass

module_name = __import__('sys').modules[__name__]
setattr(module_name, 'Mustang', Car())
setattr(module_name, 'Camaro', Car())
setattr(module_name, 'Challenger', Car())

print(Mustang)
print(Camaro)
print(Challenger)
```

to dynamically create instance of class using list of strings

```
class Car:
    pass

module_name = __import__('sys').modules[__name__]
cars = ['Mustang', 'Camaro', 'Challenger']
for car in cars:
    setattr(module_name, car, Car())

print(Mustang)
print(Camaro)
print(Challenger)
```